# Email Private Server IP Address Characteristics - How does an email inbox from a "warmed" ip verses a "cold" ip

Tags: email, ip-address, bulk-email

We send email blasts to aged lead lists so we need to use private email servers.

We recently acquired a new IP address, so we need to warm it up to ISPs so that it inboxes better.

That being said, if we email to a list using an IP that is cold and continue to email to that same list until the IP is warm will the list start to get more emails inboxed or will it follow the same inboxing behavior as before simply because the first interaction was with a cold IP?

To add to this, when warming up IPs do you tend to send emails to your cleanest and most reliable lists first?  Or do you use your poorer converting lists so that you can warm up the IP first and improve your inboxing with the more important lists?